# php on windows server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create my first dynamic site on windows server 2008 r2. I have created other dynamic sites successfully on linux based systems but I am having a little bit of trouble with this.

So i have php, mysql and phpmyadmin installed on the server.

I have a page (index.php) with the following:

```
    <?php
    include 'php/index.php';
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    ?>
```

This works fine and does not show when i do 'view source' on the displayed page in a web browser.

Further down my page i have the following:

```
    <?=$obj->get_email()?>
```

This statement is to be used to pull information from a database. When i do view source it shows the get_email() command as seen above. Instead of what it should be replaced with .

Is this a PHP issue? Is this type of command not suitable with windows server or am i just doing something completely stupid??

Comment: Have you tried it without short tags? They aren't always supported. So try `<?php echo $obj->get_email(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without short tags:

```
<?php echo $obj->get_email(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check php.ini for the setting: `short_open_tag` and change it to `1` if you wish to be able to use `<?` to jump into PHP mode.

Barring that, just changing it to `<?php echo $obj->get_email(); ?>` will fix your problem.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)